# Using react-native-netinfo to detect connection change gets old state

Tags: android, react-native, event-handling, synchronization

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app. I am using an Android device (not emulator).

Let's say I don't have internet connection an I have an array saved in my Asyncstorage and each time I push a button I insert a new item on that array.
I am using react-native-netinfo to detect when the connection changes, so what I'm trying to do is:
When the `NetInfo.addEventListener` triggers and if the connection status is `true`, I want to send that array to my API, the event is triggering well, if I turn off the wifi and cellular data I get connection status `false`, everything is ok. But when I `console.log` my array and try to send it to my API is doesn't print the new items into Asyncstorage.

If I restart the app, that same `console.log` prints the correct information when the connection changes, but again, if I push new items and the connection changes again, it doesn't print the new items added to the Asyncstorage (I know they're there because if I go to another screen, they're there)

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {


    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      handleConnectionChange(state);
      console.log("Connection type", state.type);
      console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };

}, []);

const handleConnectionChange = (state) => {

    console.log("Array: ", tickets);
    //tickets should be updated with the new tickets but is not, until I refresh the app.
    //tickets rendered ok and are printed ok on any other console.log outside of this event.

    if (state.isConnected && tickets.length > 0) {
      console.log("TRY TO SYNC");
  
      callAPI()
    } 

    setConnectionStatus(state.isConnected);
};
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.